# Efficient way to splice together two lists of lists in python

Tags: python, iterator, nested-lists

I have two nested lists in python, for instance:

```
lst1 = [
       [ [1,2],[3,4] ], [ [5,6,7],[8,9,10] ]
       ]
lst2 = [
       [ [11,12],[13,14] ], [ [15,16,17],[18,19,20] ]
       ]
```

I'd like to be able to put in an index corresponding to the flattened version of the lists, and return the "crossed-over" list:

e.g. index is 5, output is the new list

```
lst3 = [
       [ [1,2],[3,4] ], [ [5,16,17],[18,19,20] ]
       ]
```

I can do this by doing a triple nested loop but I know there must be a quicker way in python, likely using the iterator?

EDIT: I am asking how to more efficiently do the following:

```
lst1 = [
       [ [1,2],[3,4] ], [ [5,6,7],[8,9,10] ]
       ]
lst2 = [
       [ [11,12],[13,14] ], [ [15,16,17],[18,19,20] ]
       ]


lst3 = []

counter = 0
for i in xrange(len(lst1)):
    for j in xrange(len(lst1[i])):
        temp1 = []
        for k in xrange(len(lst1[i][j])):
            temp2 = []
            counter += 1
            if counter > 5:
                temp2.append(lst2[i][j][k])
            else:
                temp2.append(lst1[i][j][k])
            temp1.append(temp2)
        lst3.append(temp1)

print lst1
print lst2
print lst3
```

lst3 result:

```
[[[1], [2]], [[3], [4]], [[5], [16], [17]], [[18], [19], [20]]]
```

Comment: You're going to have to explain how that input corresponds to that output.

Comment: Work your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html#the-python-tutorial) to get an idea of the tools available to you. Maybe start by writing down on paper, in your *natural* language, the steps needed to accomplish the task.  Try to turn that into pseudo-code and finally actual code.  If you get stuck with the actual code, come back and ask.  Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by a "crossed-over" list, but it seems that you're trying to do some sort of [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) of the list.  But you also mention that you want a *flattened* list, even though your output is not flattened.

So, I'm not really sure what you're asking for.  But if I use *solely* the title as a means to guess what you're looking for, then the answer is fairly simple, using [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
>>> lst3 = [x for x in [lst1, lst2]]
```

This will give the following result:

```
>>> lst3
[[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]], [[[11, 12], [13, 14]], [[15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20]]]]
```

which is a combination of the two lists.  Not sure if it's a "combination" in the way that you want, since that can be interpreted many ways and I cannot tell exactly what you want.

Comment: The list comprehension is superfluous; `[lst1, lst2]` produces the same list already.

Comment: true.  It is superfluous.  I'd submitted it in that fashion because it *seemed* like the OP wanted to do something more with it, such as filter out one of the lists.  That's easier once already in a list comprehension.